# Почему «слать», но «шлю»?

Tags: этимология, морфология, фонетика, глаголы, историческая-фонетика

В чем причина того, что у корня с соответствующим значением есть два варианта: *слать* и *шлю*? Меня интересуют объяснения с позиции синхронии и диахронии.

Comment: Вас может заинтересовать разбор этого вопроса в учебном пособии Масловой В.А. "Истоки праславянской фонологии" (стр. 277–280). По меньшей мере диахрония там рассмотрена подробно, хотя и осталось впечатление, что открытых вопросов здесь больше, чем ответов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По аналогии с мы́шление / мы́слить, мысль; -шл- происходит из праслав. -sli̯-. Это следствие падения редуцированных и палатализации:

Зубные д, т, з, с, ц смягчаются в шипящие перед j; причем последний поглощается шипящим:

д — жд 2: сꙋди́-ти — сꙋжд-ꙋ̀ (вместо сꙋд-j-ꙋ)

т — щ: хотѣ́-ти — хощ-ꙋ̀

ст — щ: мости́-ти — мощ-ꙋ̀

з — ж: лиза́-ти — лиж-ꙋ̀

с — ш: писа́-ти — пиш-ꙋ̀

ц — ч: ѻ҆те́ц-ъ — ѻ҆те́ч-е-скїй

После падения редуцированных вновь образовавшаяся группа **сл перед ю, є, перешла тоже в шл**: глаголы типа мыслити имели в 1 л. наст. вр. формы мышл̑ѭ. Ср.: «Аще и помышлю быти патриархъ...» (Дело Ник., № 19). Совр.: мышление, промышлять и под.

сл — шл: мы́сли-ти — помышлѧ́-ти

То же самое и здесь: слать, но шлю, шлют из съл*, съли.тъ и под.